# DevExpress form inheritance bug?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I have base class inherited from DE class :

```
public class MyFormBase : RibbonForm {}
```

and inherited from mine:

```
public class SomeForm : MyFormBase {}
```

All compiles and working well, except for Visual Studio Designer. For MyFormBase it show everything perfectly fine, but for SomeForm it shows this error (and it is in the same assembly!!):

```
Could not load file or assembly 'BlendDesc-Ln.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

What is this file? Some sources says it is Microsoft Plugin, but it is more like no one knows about it at all. I simply want to add some layer between my form and DE form and I can't do this?

I met other solutions like add attribute above your base class or check DEBUG constant on compilation, and then each time you need to do something JUST: clean solution -> close VS -> rebuild -> change something. It is just stupid if you have more than 100 forms.

Comment: AFAIK, `BlendDesc-Ln.dll` is a DLL file required by Blend feature for VS, seems that you need to repair Blend installation and might not related with DX current settings.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error is not related neither to DevExpress not to visual inheritance. It seems something wrong with your VS environment. Try to **repair** your Visual Studio installation and/or **remove/disable installed VS extension** one by one.

To me, this file is located at `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\`. And removing this file does not affect Windows Forms designer at all.

Comment: Tryed repair - no changes. VS in safemode - no changes.